# find content from an array in a string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am making a java applet that you can copy an email into and compare for Spam content.  I have most done but i am having an issue with comparing the words.This is my code i am having issues with.

```
    int SpamCounter = 0;

    String[] spamWords = new String[] {
        "Various words"
        };

    String EmailInput = EmailTA.getText();


    String sWords = Arrays.toString(spamWords);

    for (String spamWord : spamWords) {
        if (EmailInput.equalsIgnoreCase(sWords) )
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Yes " + spamWord);
            SpamCounter = SpamCounter++ ;
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No " + spamWord);

        }
    }
    String result = "Your Spam Count is: " + SpamCounter ;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, result);
}
```

Comment: compare a string against an array of words? sounds like you are in need of [tokenization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Tokenization)

Comment: Get rid of **sWords**. This does nothing for you since taking an array of spam words and turning it into a comma delimited string then comparing that comma delimited string against the string content of the entire email message with **equalsIgnoreCase()** is going to prove somewhat more than fruitless. Instead of using **equalsIgnoreCase()** try using the **String.contains()** method instead (for starters): `if (EmailInput.toLowerCase().contains(spamWord.toLowerCase()) { ... `. See how that works for you...then advance from there.

Comment: This worked.  thank you